# Stored Procedure with EF Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a Database First DB in EF Core 2. Can this be done by using the OnModelCreating method of the Context class?

Comment: If you mean mapping the `DbSet` CRUD operations to stored procedures, no.